# Dart gives Unhandled Exception: type is not a subtype of type of 'value'

Tags: dart, types, casting

I have an abstract class `ImageUpdate`. Two classes, `NewImage` and `ExistingImage` implement `ImageUpdate`.

I have a variable `imageUpdates` of type `List<ImageUpdate>`.

When I try adding a variable of type `NewImage` to the List, I get this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'NewImage' is not a subtype of type 'ExistingImage' of 'value'
```

I am pretty stumped, since the list is of `ImageUpdate` and not `ExistingImage`, so I have no idea how to debug it, especially since Dart is type safe (nowhere am I using `dynamic`).

Comment: It's very hard to answer this question without seeing reproducible code.  My guess is that you *think* you have a `List<ImageUpdate>` but it's actually a `List<ExistingImage>`.  For example, that could happen if you had `List<ImageUpdate> list = <ExistingImage>[];` and then tried to add a `NewImage` to `list`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that you have code similar to:

```dart
class Base {}

class Derived1 extends Base {}

class Derived2 extends Base {}

List<Base> makeList() {
  var list = [Derived1()];
  return list;
}

void main() {
  var list = makeList();
  list.add(Derived2()); // TypeError
}
```

What happens is that the `List` object is originally created as a `List<Derived1>`. (That is, `list.runtimeType` will be something like `List<Derived1>`, not its *static* (declared) type of `List<Base>`.) Then, when you try to add a `Derived2` object to `list`, it will fail at runtime because `list`'s actual, runtime type is `List<Derived1>`, which does not allow `Derived2` elements.

This ultimately stems from Dart allowing implicit type conversions from `GenericClass<Derived>` to `GenericClass<Base>` if `Derived` derives from `Base`.  This is useful in many cases, but it also can lead to situations like this one that fail at runtime.

You can fix this by explicitly stating that you want a `List<Base>` object:

```dart
List<Base> makeList() {
  var list = <Base>[Derived1()]; // Note the explicit type.
  return list;
}
```

or, if that's not possible, by creating a new `List<Base>` object:

- `var list = <Base>[...makeList()];`
- `var list = List<Base>.from(makeList());`

(In this particular situation, `List.of(makeList())` also would work since it would create a new `List` object with the static type, but I wouldn't use that since being explicit about the type conversion would be more readable.)