# Setting timeout callback on a HttpClientRequest future throws unhandled exception

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to set the `onTimeout` callback on a [HttpClientRequest](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.1/dart-io/HttpClientRequest-class.html) future's `timeout` [method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.3/dart-async/Future/timeout.html).

The example below compiles without error. However, when run it throws the following unhandled exception:

`type '() => Future<HttpClientRequest>' is not a subtype of type '(() => FutureOr<_HttpClientRequest>)?' of 'onTimeout'`.

I'm new to dart/flutter and am having trouble understanding why the callback method fails.

```dart
void main() async {
  requestify();
}

Future<HttpClientRequest> requestify() async {
  var client = HttpClient();
  var request = client.get('10.255.255.1', 80, '');
  // request.timeout(const Duration(seconds: 1));
  request.timeout(const Duration(seconds: 1), onTimeout: () {
    print('timed out');
    return request;
  });
  return request;
}
```

Comment: return request; inside the onTimeout function doesn't return the request to requestify function it returns it to the onTimeout function itself, but onTimeout expects a return type of FutureOr but the request is of type Future, just remove return request inside onTimeout function

Comment: If I remove `return request;` I get `Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'FutureOr<HttpClientRequest>' doesn't allow null.`

Comment: you can return timeout message just like in the documentation: onTimeout: () => 'timeout', or you can remove the onTimeout completely since we care only about the duration.

Comment: If I use `return 'my string';` I get `Error: A value of type 'String' can't be returned from a function with return type 'FutureOr<HttpClientRequest>'`. My understanding is that the documentation example returns `'timeout'` because the example type is a `Future<String>`.

Comment: you're right sorry I didn't pay much attention, what about making the HttpClientRequest nullable meaning that if there is a timeout it will return null otherwise it returns a HttpClientRequest, and you can check if the response is not null

Comment: If I make it nullable I get `type '() => Null' is not a subtype of type '(() => FutureOr<_HttpClientRequest>)?' of 'onTimeout'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the type error more closely:

> `type '() => Future<HttpClientRequest>' is not a subtype of type '(() => FutureOr<_HttpClientRequest>)?' of 'onTimeout'.`

You supply a callback function that returns a `Future<HttpClientRequest>`.

What's expected is a function that returns a `FutureOr<_HttpClientRequest>`.

`FutureOr<T>` is a special union of types `T` and `Future<T>`, so a function that returns a `Future<HttpCientRequest>` is a subtype of (i.e., is compatible with) a function that returns a `FutureOr<HttpClientRequest>`.  However, what's expected is a `FutureOr<_HttpClientRequest>`. `_HttpClientRequest`?  Where did that come from, and why isn't that compatible?

Even without knowing the implementation details, we can presume that `_HttpClientRequest` is some subtype of `HttpClientRequest`.  The error message implies that when we call `HttpClient.get`, the *static* (known at compile-time) type of the returned object is `Future<HttpClientRequest>`, but the actual *runtime* type is `Future<_HttpClientRequest>`.  If type `Derived` is a subtype of `Base`, then Dart also treats `GenericClass<Derived>` as a subtype of `GenericClass<Base>`.  Normally this is okay, and returning a narrower subtype of what a function is declared to return is safe.

The problem occurs when you then try to call `.timeout` on that returned `Future<_HttpClientRequest>`.  `Future<T>.timeout`'s callback must return a `FutureOr<T>`.  However, you're calling `.timeout` on an object whose runtime type is `Future<_HttpClientRequest>`, so your callback must return an `_HttpClientRequest` too.  Returning the base class type (`HttpClientRequest`) is not valid since you can't return a broader type where a narrower type is expected.

(See [Dart gives Unhandled Exception: type is not a subtype of type of 'value'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69998722/) for another case where treating `GenericClass<Derived>` as a subtype of `GenericClass<Base>` can lead to surprising runtime errors.)

### TL;DR

As far as the analyzer and compiler know, you're calling `.timeout` on a `Future<HttpClientRequest>` with a callback that returns an `HttpClientRequest`, so there's no compile-time error.  However, at runtime, you're actually calling `.timeout` on a `Future<_HttpClientRequest>` with a callback that returns an `HttpClientRequest`, so you end up with a runtime error.

### How can you fix this?

Some options:

- Consider filing [a Dart SDK issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues) about `HttpClient.get` returning an object whose runtime type is `Future<_HttpClientRequest>` instead of a `Future<HttpClientRequest>`.
- Since `_HttpClientRequest` is a private type, you can't actually return an object of that type yourself.  You can, however, use `Future.value` to construct a new `Future<HttpClientRequest>` out of the `Future<_HttpClientRequest>`:

  ```dart
    // `client.get` might return a `Future` that completes to a subtype of
    // `HttpClientRequest`.
    var request = Future<HttpClientRequest>.value(client.get('10.255.255.1', 80, ''));
    request.timeout(const Duration(seconds: 1), onTimeout: () {
      print('timed out');
      return request;
    });
    return request;
  }
  ```
- Avoid the weirdness with the callback type by not using `Future.timeout` with a callback and instead catching the resulting `TimeoutException`.

I'll also point out that `Future.timeout` returns a new `Future`, but you're returning the original `Future`, and the value returned by the `timeout` callback won't ever be used.  I don't know if that's what you intend, although in this case it's probably fine if all you want to do is log that a request took too long.

Answer (score 1):

```
Future<HttpClientRequest?> requestify() async {
  try {
    var client = HttpClient();
    var request = await client.get("10.255.255.1", 80, "")
                       .timeout(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    return request;
  } on TimeoutException catch(e) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

then in the main function

```
final response = await requestify();
if (response != null) {
   // HttpClientRequest
} else {
   // timeout
}
```